# Convert PythonMagick Image object to numpy array (for OpenCV) and then to PIL image object

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, pythonmagick

I want to convert a PythonMagick Image Object to a NumPy array that can be used in OpenCV, and then I want to convert it into a PIL image object.  I have searched Google but cannot find any sources explaining how to do this.  Can someone show me how to convert image objects between these different modules?

Comment: What is your question? You can't expect and answer if you don't ask a question. Also show some own efforts. [ask]

Comment: thank you I have changed it , i just want to convert them into different formats like directly from PythonMagick Image object to Numpy array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Because you're a new user, your question came up for review.  i have edited the title and the phrasing to make it clearer what you're asking.  If you disagree with the edits, you can edit your question further.

Comment: Ya I'm  totally new and my english is terrible

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way that I've found consist in saving and opening it:

```
import PythonMagic
import cv2

# pm_img is a PythonMagick.Image
pm_img.write('path/to/temporary/file.png')
np_img = cv2.imread('path/to/temporary/file.png')
```

I haven't found any satisfactory way to convert PythonMagick images to NumPy arrays without saving them, but there is a slow way that involves using python loops:

```
import PythonMagick
import numpy as np

pm_img = PythonMagick.Image('path/to/image.jpg')
h, w = pm_img.size().height(), pm_img.size().width()
np_img = np.empty((h, w, 3), np.uint16) # PythonMagick opens images with 16 bit depth
                                        # It seems to store the same byte twice (weird)

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        # OpenCV stores pixels as BGR
        np_img[i, j] = (pm_img.pixelColor(j, i).quantumBlue(),
                        pm_img.pixelColor(j, i).quantumGreen(),
                        pm_img.pixelColor(j, i).quantumRed())
np_img = np_img.astype(np.uint8)
```

Converting NumPy arrays to PIL images is easier:

```
from PIL import Image

pil_img = Image.fromarray(np_img[:, :, ::-1].astype(np.uint8))
```

Since PIL stores images in RGB but OpenCV stores them in BGR it's necessary to change the order of the channels (`[:, :, ::-1]`).

`Image.fromarray()` takes a NumPy array with dtype `np.uint8`.